# Can we use the bitcoin idea to get rid of traditional password schemes? (usernames, hashing)

Tags: security, cryptography, passwords, bitcoin, password-hash

I considered the traditional password hashing:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846

However, bitcoin has a way of letting people use human readable seed phrases as a recovery secret for their "accounts" (BIP-39):
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase

They can use 12-24 English random words from a list, hence the set of words has a high entropy.
This helps a traditional way of backing up important secrets on a piece of paper vs. backing up a very long crypto key.

From the high entropy seed, they derive programatically an ECDSA key pair or a tree of keys and use the public key as identifier and the private key to sign challenges that can be verified with the public key.

Could we use a similar system to get rid of some problems of traditional password authentication? (like sending plain text passwords and hashing computer intensively on server with a lot of cloud costs, using personally identifyable data as usernames, not knowing if the server hashes correctly or what they do with our personal data)

As a side note: the problem of phishing secrets can be solved with autofill or careful,  infrequent manual use of secrets.

The idea:

- generate like 25 random base32 tokens (26 letters + 10 numbers - I,O,1,0) as a human readable passcode which can be stored in a pass manager or on a post-it or anywhere (12-24 words are a lot of character, readability can be achieved with reduced character number and visual separators too)
- instead of password hashing on server, we can hash the passcode on the client with pbkdf2 to a seed and use the seed to generate ECDSA key pairs just like with BIP-32:
  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0032
- the public key would serve as a kind of username (anonymous), stored on the server instead of password hashes
- if leaked, a brute force attack would have to recreate the computer intensive password hashing process to attack the private key, the same way if we store password hashes on the server
- by authentication, the client would do the hashing, provide the public key and sign over some random server challenge with the private key, the server would verify the existence of public key and find the corresponding internal user id and verify the signature with the public key

This seems to be a Pareto-improvement over traditional password management:

- the secret will not travel
- the server load is minimal since the cpu intensive password hashing happens on the client side
- if the public keys leak on the server, it is similar to when the password hashes leak: a brute force attack has to perform the intensive pbkdf2 hashing process (that is why I would use password hashing to get the seed)
- no personal usernames
- transparent password hashing

It may even be used with traditional schemes like username/email/phone number + password.
The inital entropy is not that huge typically and salting is not really meaningful so a kind of global salt (pepper) could be used. However, what we lose by not salting each entry separately, we win by the username because it is not stored plain text on a compromised server, so the entropy is actually higher when password hashing username+password on client.

As for implementation, I considered the following library:
https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip32/blob/master/src/bip32.js

But there may be native methods in web crypto API to do the same.

Answer (score -2):

There is an existing approach that uses ECDSA and/or Ed25519 key pairs that was recently standardized, called [*passkeys*](https://fidoalliance.org/passkeys/).  These use the same technology as FIDO2 security keys (such as YubiKeys), but they are stored in a way that can be transferred across machines.  Instead of generating them with a seed, they're just generated pseudorandomly and stored in an encrypted storage of some sort (which may be password protected in the normal way).  They can generally be used on most websites that support FIDO2 with little additional work.

As you mention, the advantage is that the server has only a public key, and those are already assumed to be universally known as part of the security model.  Since they're generated with a CSPRNG, assuming the CSPRNG is secure, they're functionally impossible to guess.  Additionally, they're unique per site and can't be associated with other passkeys, so site A can't correlate its users with site B based on the credentials alone.

Many sites will still use a username because it's convenient to have an identifier for the user in relation to interactions with other users or for support.  It's up to each site to decide.

Note that for SSH, OpenSSH already provides FIDO2-based security keys as a special key type, so users can use ECDSA or Ed25519 keys where the storage is backed as a security key, and SSH keys already benefit from many of the same benefits as passkeys.

Comment: Nice marketing for passkeys but my question was totally different, use the bitcoin idea. Many people want to store their secrets locally and have total control of it, storing private keys did not work (long) so the idea is to have strong human friendly codes as a starting point. Passkeys are private keys managed by syncing cloud pass managers. Not everybody can/wants to use complex pass managers. The "bitcoin idea" is already a step forward from passkeys that does not respect people who do not want to use built in or cross platform pass managers. And it has plenty of other flaws too.

Comment: Any site can use usernames if they need it, internally. Usernames do not need to be part of the authentication process, especially emails. If you write a fido/passkey marketing blog post, you surely know that passkey and especially the authentication tech behind passkeys does not need usernames. They call a passkey id user id (and user handle at a different place, eh...) but it is actually what is used by authentication in the background.

Comment: I think the bitcoin idea is also a Pareto-improvement over the passkey idea: the creation of the secret does not happen in an Apple/Google/Microsoft system (and using not so random generator by ECDSa private key creation in a closed source environment may make it weak to US national agencies). You have the real choice how you want to manage your secrets: paper, local disk, pass manager. You have ONE secret and not 3,4,5,6 passkeys. Passkeys will be a maintenance hell, users can delete them without telling, create another one, change username labels without letting know etc.

Comment: I get that you are a fido/passkey supporter but the question again: "Can we use the bitcoin idea to get rid of traditional password schemes?" Like can I get a gin-tonic? Bar tender: there is an existing approach that you pour coca-cola (link to company website) on shitty whiskey (link to fido standard) and you get an alcoholic drink. And let companies decide whether they want to use big amounts of sugar in their drinks or not! Drinks dont require sugar. You should enter the bar sugar free and decide whether you want to drink sugar (give personally identifyable info).

Comment: You asked, “Can we use a similar system to [solve these problems]?”  I said, yes, there's an existing system you can use.  You can build passkeys using whatever approach you want, including your Bitcoin-based approach if you prefer.  The standard is storage-neutral and you can use a local, open-source password manager if you want or generate them on the fly.  However, generating keys deterministically can pose problems if you need to rotate credentials.